# How to check and uncheck a checkbox infinitely?

Tags: javascript

I have this code, I tried with the setTimeout, promises and callback functions with no luck.

```
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((el, i) => {
    setTimeout(() => { 
        el.checked = true 
    }, i * 300);
})
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sistematico/rc5nqbjf/96/)

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Change `setTimeout` to `setInterval` and `el.checked = true` to `el.checked = !el.checked`. It would exhibit a wierd behaviour though. Can you ellaborate more what you need?

Comment: @Major_Ash check and un-check in sequence.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sistematico/rc5nqbjf/99 very close to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setup()` function sets a timeout on each checkbox. When the last one fires, it sets them all up again:

```
function setup() {
  document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((el, i) => {
    setTimeout(() => { 
      el.checked = ! el.checked
      if ( i+1 == document.querySelectorAll("input").length) {
        setup()
      }
    }, i * 300);
  }
)}

setup()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2u9rqot1/